# Two different definitions of Gateaux differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My textbook defines Gateaux derivative as the following:

> (Definition) A mapping $F: D\subset \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m} $ is Gateaux-differentiable at an interior point $x$ of of D if there eixsts a linear operator $A\in L(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R^m} )$ such that, for any $h\in \mathbb{R^n} $, $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\| F(x+th) - F(x) - tAh\|}{t} = 0.$$

However, the definition on wikipedia (and every other online source) use definition like: $F$ is G-differentiable at $x$ if the limit $$a_h:=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{F(x+th) -F(x)}{t}$$ exists for all $h\in \mathbb{R^m}$.
Yet this two definitions do not seem to be equivalent to me.
What I did is to rewrite the second definition to the form
$$ \lim_{t\to0}\frac{ \|F(x+th) -F(x) - ta_h\|}{t}  = 0, $$

which seems to suggest that theose two definitions are equivalent iff there exists $A \in L(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R^m} )$ such that $Ah = a_h $ for all $h$. But this is not always the case, so the two definitions are not the same. I would appreciate if someone could let me know whether this reasoning is correct.

Comment: It seems that your book is using the definition of ""total"" or """Frechet""" derivative (a.k.a. _the definition_ of derivative) to define """Gateux""" derivative, which is strange since the point of the latter is to avoid the former and to talk about rates of change along curves and directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right. the two definitions are not quite of the same thing. If you take
$$   \frac{x^2y}{x^2 + y^2}   $$
there is a directional derivative in any direction $(a,b),$ namely $\frac{a^2 b}{a^2 + b^2}.$  I just wrote $x=ta$ and $y=tb$  and found your limit.

However, there is no linear mapping, as the derivative is $0$  along either axis but nonzero in the $x=y$ direction.

Next, we can have a linear operator yet still fall short of Frechet differentiability. Example
$$ \frac{x^5 y^5}{x^{12} + y^8} $$
where the derivative along any straight line through the origin is zero. However, poor behavior when $y = x^{3/2}.$

Note: for a function that is continuous at the origin, value $0$ there and first partials there also zero, Frechet differentiability would mean  that the limit of $ \frac{|f(h)|}{|h|}, \; \;  $ as $h$ goes to zero, comes out to be zero.