# An application of Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

In my convex optimization textbook, there is statement that goes as follows:

> Using Stokes' theorem from calculus, we have $$\nabla \int_Bf(x+v)dv = \int_Sf(x+u)\frac{u}{\|u\|}du. $$

Here $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function, $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ corresponds to the unit ball, and $S$ its surface.

However, I have failed to see how Stokes' theorem comes into play. More specifically, I do not see notions like curl, surface, or boundary appearing in this equation.  The only intuition I have is when $f: \mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, then this is simply a consequence of fundamental theorem of calculus. Yet this argument clearly does not apply to higher dimensional case.

I would appreciate explanations on how Stokes' theorem is applied here.

Comment: I think they're referring to the more general version:$$\int_\Omega d\omega= \int_{\partial\Omega} \omega.$$ In this case the operator $d$ acting on the differential form $\omega$ would be given by the gradient (acting on 0-forms).

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at the identity component-wise and use the divergence theorem for an appropriate vector field.

Comment: I'm collecting good math textbooks. If you don't mind, please share the names of textbook you are using in this thread and in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179224/two-different-definitions-of-gateaux-differentiability) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547842/expressing-the-covariance-between-two-functions-of-gaussian-vectors). I'm sorry for this convenience...

Comment: @Akira The textbooks are "Introduction to Online Convex Optimization" by Elad Hazan, and "Random field and geometry" by Robert J Adler. But I don't think that they are math textbooks (the first is for machine learning theory and the second for probability).

Comment: @BihuDuo They are certainly math-heavy :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @Jose27 suggested, this is a vector equality, so you should prove it component by component. The $i$th component of the LHS is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_B f(x+v)\,dv = \int_B \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x+v)\,dv.$$
This is the integral over $B$ of the divergence of the vector field $\vec F = (0,\dots,0,f,0\dots,0)$, where $f$ is in the $i$th slot. Now, what is the flux of $\vec F$ over $S$? (Remember that the unit normal at $u$ to a sphere centered at the origin is $u/\|u\|$.)